# how to search item in a multi-column listview control using a textbox in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a windows form application using c#. I have used a listview control with its view property set to Details. It has two columns, ID and Name The data in the listview is data-bounded.

Now, i want to add search capability to the listview control using a textbox i.e. whatever string entered to the textbox will be searched over listview items in both the columns, ID and Name and when the item is found it gets selected and will become the top item of the listview.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ListViewItem foundItem = listView1.FindItemWithText(textBox1.Text, false, 0, true);
            if (foundItem != null)
            {
                listView1.TopItem = foundItem;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? Where do you need help?

Comment: I want, that whatever text entered in the textbox will be searched against both the columns and once the item was found then it got selected and automatically comes to the top of the listview.

Comment: I found the above code over msdn but it doesn't work on my application. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171644(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you Set the View to list to use the FindItemWithText method when initializing the ViewList? If not add the below line while initilizing your listview. without it, FindItemWithText method wont work.

```
listView1.View = View.List;
```

Edit: I found the issue is in your listView1.TopItem = foundItem;
The method actually found the data you search, but it couldn't add it to top of your list. Setting TopItem always have issues. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.topitem.aspx
Anyway, your search works fine.
Try to add your FoundItem to a new list, It'll work..

Comment: please add the complete code including ListBox initialization. So that we can figure out where excatly the error is.

Comment: I found the issue is in your listView1.TopItem = foundItem;
The method actually found the data you search, but it couldn't add it to top of your list. Setting TopItem always have issues. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.topitem.aspx
Anyway, your search works fine..